# Firebase doens't provide iOS event to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm using Firebase through BigQuery to create some dashboards based on our mobile App event tracking.

Everything worked fine until couple weeks ago, where all iOS events were not reported to BigQuery. The date matches with an App release (and we have released couple time since but the issue is still here), even though we didn't change anything about event tracking.

Even more weird, iOS events are visible on Firebase, meaning that Firebase continue to track & record properly all events... it just doesn't provide the data to BigQuery.

No issue with Android event.

Anybody experienced/experiencing the same issue ?
I contacted Firebase support and they were pretty vague on what could cause this.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer received from the Firebase team was probably vague due to the nature of the question. For example, what process did you implement to have iOS *events* report to BigQuery? Is there any code involved? If the time the trouble occurred coincided with an App release, that would indicate something is different in that release. Does the prior release still work? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Michael, How did you resolve this issue? I am getting the same issue when its working perfectly for the Android but iOS firebase events are not syncing to the big query.